# Retrieving GAE data via Key

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to python & google app engine so this is going to be a basic question but I cannot find an answer elsewhere ...

I'm trying to retrieve a record by passing the key (as generated by GAE) from an HTML page back to python.

My html call is

```
<a href="/playerprofile?uid=ahRkZXZ-Y293YnJpZGdlYm9va2luZ3IWCxIGTWVtYmVyIgpKb2huIEpvbmVzDA">John Jones</a>
```

I'm then trying to pull it out of the table like this

```
uid = self.request.get('uid')
m = Member.all().filter('Key = ',uid)
```

It doesn't retrieve anything.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like this.  The key is encoded in a urlsafe form

You should construct the Key from the encoded key using `Key(encoded=None)`

```
k = Key(uid)
m = Member.get(k)
```

Docs on Key https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass

However given you are new to appengine you should not be using **db**.  You should start using **ndb** as the datastore api, as that is where the development investment from google is going.

If you use ndb for this scenario you would use the following

```
m = Key(urlsafe=uid).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Model.get_by_key_name()` instead:

```
uid = self.request.get('uid')
m = Member.get_by_key_name(uid)
```

Here's more info about it on the [App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_key_name).